# SQL query to find cumulative GAP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find Cumulative Grade Point Average (CGPA) from `dbo.Marks` table. It's columns are given below:

- FirstName
- LastName
- RollNumber
- AdmissionYear
- Batch
- DegreeProgram
- Semester
- CourseCode
- CourseTitle
- CreditHours
- ScoreTotal
- ScoreObtained
- GPA
- Percentage
- GradeText

I am trying this Query i.e,

```
select FirstName as Name, GPA AS CGPA from dbo.Marks where FirstName='Nabia' ;
```

But, it is not showing my desire answer.

Cumulative Grade Point Average (CGPA) = CreditHours * GPA/ SUM CreditHours

Anybody can tell me, how can I get CGPA from this desire table?

Comment: @ydoow, Please see my edit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUM(CreditHours * GPA) / SUM(CreditHours) AS CGPA
FROM
    dbo.Marks
WHERE
    FirstName = 'Nabia';
```

Comment: It's really helpfull.